# CNN returns same classification for different images in production

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, multilabel-classification

I'm having an issue with my already trained neural network as I try to restore it from disk (previously saved to it after finishing training) so I can use it in production. It is a CNN that asks the user (through CLI), the path to a chest x-ray image he wants the network to analyze, and then the network is supposed to output the multi-label classification of the image into 15 different possible lung diseases categories.

My problem is that, no matter what image I give to it, it always outputs the exact same classification. It's like it completely ignores the image I feed into it. I even tried feeding images that it was trained on, and the same issue still occurred.

This is the code for my script that reads the network from the disk and analyses the pictures: (if it's relevant enough I can also put the code for the training and testing of the network, which is a different script)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

DISEASE_CATEGORIES = ["Atelectasis", "Cardiomegaly", "Consolidation", "Edema", "Effusion", "Emphysema", "Fibrosis", "Hernia", "Infiltration", 
                      "Mass", "Module", "No Finding", "Pleural_Thickening", "Pneumonia", "Pneumothorax"]
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
COLOR_CHANNELS = 1
MODEL_SCOPE = 'alexnet_cnn'

def main():
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        try:
            # Restore network that was previously saved to disk
            saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./nn_production_model/cnn_lung_diseases.ckpt.meta')
            saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./nn_production_model'))
        except:
            print('Failed to load network from disk.')
        else:
            graph = tf.get_default_graph()
            input_batch = graph.get_tensor_by_name('%s/input_batch:0' % MODEL_SCOPE)
            is_training = graph.get_tensor_by_name('%s/is_training:0' % MODEL_SCOPE)
            predicted_diseases_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('%s/predicted_diseases:0' % MODEL_SCOPE)

            filename = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[])
            image_to_analyze_tensor = read_image_in_path(filename)

            print('================================== Welcome to the Chest X-rays analysis DSS! ==================================')

            while True:
                image_path = input('\nPlease, input the path to the image you want to analyze: ')

                image_to_analyze = sess.run(image_to_analyze_tensor, feed_dict={filename: image_path})

                predicted_diseases = sess.run(predicted_diseases_tensor, feed_dict={
                        input_batch: image_to_analyze,
                        is_training: False
                })

                print('\nAnalysis Results:')
                [print('- %s: %.2f%%' % (DISEASE_CATEGORIES[i], (predicted_diseases[0][i] * 100))) for i in range(len(DISEASE_CATEGORIES))]

def read_image_in_path(filename):
    """
    Reads a PNG image from the path provided.

    Args:
        filename (Tensor): Scalar string tensor with the path of the image.

    Returns:
        Tensor: Image in provided path, fully decoded, rescaled, resized and reshaped.
    """
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=COLOR_CHANNELS)
    image_rescaled = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    image_resized = tf.image.resize(image_rescaled, [IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT])
    image_reshaped = tf.reshape(image_resized, [1, IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, COLOR_CHANNELS])

    return image_reshaped

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `input_batch` is the Tensor that holds batches of images to feed to the network (in this case, it'll only hold the one specified by the user). The `is_training` is a just a scalar boolean value to tell whether the network is training or not. The `predicted_diseases_tensor` is the tensor that will actually hold the multi-label classification for the image to be analyzed.

Comment: The code you're showing looks fine. So maybe your graph isn't hooked up the way you think it is. Have you tried viewing the graph in tensorboard, for example?

Comment: Are you normalizing the new images the same as the training set? I don't see any division by 255 or substraction of the image mean.

Comment: @mdaoust not yet. i will try that now!

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro it is doing that on the `image_rescaled` code line. The conversion from `uint8` to `float32` automaticaly rescales the image. But I also tried loading the image with the exact same function as I did in training (which was different), I debugged the code in both places and the image was 100% equal in both, and the problem still happened.

Comment: Also, with tensorflow 2.0 and eager mode, you might be able to simplify things by dropping the graphs and sessions.

Comment: @mdaoust yeah, i know. this is my first time using tensorflow, so I'm still learning. i wanted to use the already implemented AlexNet architecture in in the `tf.contrib` module of tensorflow, but the 2.0 version didn't have it anymore, so I had to use 1.14

Comment: @TiagoSilva, is your issue resolved ?

Comment: Nop, never managed found out the issue. But this was a university project, and I'm no longer working on it either